# Inject Map without any @IntoMap bindings

Tags: dagger-2

I'm using Dagger to inject a `Map<Int,Handler>` into a class. It works perfectly when something like this is defined in a module:

```java
@Binds
@IntoMap
@IntKey(FOO_KEY)
Handler bindFooHandler(FooHandler handler);
```

If no such methods exist, the project fails to build because it doesn't know of a `Map<Integer,Handler>` to inject. Is there any way to make `Map<Integer,Handler>` injectable when no `@IntoMap` bindings exist?

Comment: What do you want to inject in that case, an empty map?

Comment: Ideally, yeah. But it could be also be null or `Optional`. I know there is a `@BindsOptionalOf` annotation but I'm not entire sure how it works and wasn't able to find any examples of using it with multibinding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in the [Declaring Multibindings](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/multibindings.html#declaring-multibindings) area of the Dagger doc site. Emphasis mine:

> You do not have to use `@Multibinds` for sets or maps that have at least one `@IntoSet`, `@ElementsIntoSet`, or `@IntoMap` binding, but **you do have to declare them if they may be empty**.

This would go in your `@Module`, which would necessarily be an interface or abstract class: `@Multibinds` cannot have an implementation. For your case you'd see:

```java
@Multibinds abstract Map<Integer, Handler> bindEmptyMap();
```

Don't worry about having that binding appear in more than one place in your graph. As in the above doc site, duplicated into the [@Multibinds](https://dagger.dev/api/latest/dagger/multibindings/Multibinds.html) docs (also emphasis mine):

> **A given set or map multibinding can be declared any number of times without error.** Dagger never implements or calls any @Multibinds methods.